# Turning on map view in Google Earth?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I want to toggle between map view and satellite imagery in Google Earth like I can in Google Maps.

Is there an easy way to add Map View to Google Earth?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a Google AppSpot website that will let you overlay Google Maps (and many others) in Google Earth for Free
(You do need have a gmail account and allow the site monitor your usage)

[image]

[image]

http://ge-map-overlays.appspot.com/

Comment: Still works in October 2021

Answer (score 6):

Google doesn't allow it. There are some folks in the Google Earth Forums that have found some "unofficial" workarounds: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/earth/thread?tid=4a722cff2ea80a5c&hl=en. Complied from a few posts on those forums:

> http://www.gelib.com/google-maps.htm
>
> http://www.mgmaps.com/kml/
>
> http://bernhard.sterzbach.de/googlemapsoverlay.html
>
> http://ge-map-overlays.appspot.com/