# How to put a roads layer (OpenStreetMap) on top of KML polygons?

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-gis, kml

I need to develop a map where KMLs are overlayed with road layers. So, KMLs are polygons, and I would need to use a map tiles like OpenStreetMaps. But the problem is how to put roads on top of KML areas? What do you suggest me? I would like to use some open source software.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16044/why-cant-i-turn-on-a-map-view-in-google-earth

Comment: I'm not sure that helps.

Comment: Can you explain what else you need? I guess you have specific goals, but they aren't being communicated effectively. Saying "not useful" doesn't really help us to help you.

Comment: I need to develop a web map with any open source software which will show OpenStreetMaps. Then I need to add KML polygons and on the top of polygons I need to put roads. What do you suggest? How to add layer roads, does some shapefile or KML with world roads exists somewhere on the web or?

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers will do this, eg when using a transparent wms.

http://docs.openlayers.org/library/introduction.html#adding-an-overlay-wms

Comment: Can I add WMS with roads only? Where I can find it?